# How to groupby and transform in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe below

```
A B C
1 1 a
1 2 b       
1 3 c
2 4 d
2 5 e
```

I would ilke to transform like below

```
A B C
1 6 a
2 9 d
```

B means the sum of group and C is the first elements in previous df

How can I get this result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need `groupby` with `aggregation` - `sum` and `first`:

```
df = df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'sum','C':'first'}).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  6  a
1  2  9  d
```

Thank you [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201834/how-to-groupby-and-transform-in-pandas#comment71565566_42201865) for another solution:

```
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg({'B':'sum','C':'first'}).reindex(columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  6  a
1  2  9  d
```

Comment: `df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg({'B':'sum','C':'first'})`?